# Document left space is on wrong side

Tags: spacing

I just wrote my bachelor thesis and I want to print it.

Because I want to print it two sided, the text should have some more space on the left side on the uneven numbered pages and some more space on the right side on the even pages.

But it is exactly the opposite. I got this code:

```
\documentclass[
     12pt,                    % font size
     a4paper,             % paper format
     BCOR10mm,     % binding correction
     DIV14,                 % stripe size for margin calculation
     listof=totoc,                    % table listing in toc
     bibliography=totoc,       % bibliography in toc
     index=totoc,              % index in toc
%     parskip            % paragraph skip instead of paragraph indent
     twoside,
     headsepline
     ]{scrreprt}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The outer margin of should be twice as wide as the inner margin of a single side in a twosided document. Use option `BCOR=<length>` to add a binding correction. See also KOMA-Script documentation section "Fundamentals of Page Layout"  and figure 2.1. "Double-sided layout with the box construction of the classical division factor of 9, after subtraction of a binding correction".

Comment: You may try `DIV=12` instead of `DIV14`...

Comment: At http://digital.nls.uk/gutenberg-bible/pageturner.cfm?mode=gallery_grid&id=74481668&sn=1 you can see thumbnails of Gutenberg's Bible. You can clearly see it has outer margins wider than inner margins. For a more modern book, “Kidnapped” by R. L. Stevenson: http://digital.nls.uk/rlstevenson/browse/pageturner.cfm?mode=gallery_grid&id=74462954&sn=1

Comment: The LaTeX lengths `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` are used for this task.  If one wishes to leave  a binding width, then `\oddsidemargin` should be set to that binding width, and `\evensidemargin` should be the negative of it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How do I use them?

Comment: @PaulGaborit This doesn't change it.

Comment: In the preamble, for example, `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1cm}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This fixed it for me, mind to write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX lengths `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` are used for the task of allocating a binding width. For a document class that sets the pages symmetrically, if one wishes to leave a binding width, then `\oddsidemargin` should be set to that binding width, and `\evensidemargin` should be the negative of it.

In the case of the `scrreprt` class, the margins are already biased, and so the above rule does not strictly apply (one may verify that `\the\oddsidemargin; \the\evensidemargin` yields `3.60402pt; 22.57254pt`).  What I did in the MWE below is to produce an exaggerated case wherein the margins were shifted all the way to the page boundary, using `\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3.4cm}` and `\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2.5cm}`.

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[
     12pt,                    % font size
     a4paper,             % paper format
     BCOR10mm,     % binding correction
     DIV=12,                 % stripe size for margin calculation
     listof=totoc,                    % table listing in toc
     bibliography=totoc,       % bibliography in toc
     index=totoc,              % index in toc
%     parskip            % paragraph skip instead of paragraph indent
     twoside,
     headsepline
     ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3.4cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-2.5cm}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a reasonable value, just back off from these numbers towards zero an equal amount on the two lengths, for example,

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.0cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.1cm}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use

```
BCOR=10mm,
twoside=semi
```

to get inner margins with the same width as the outer margins and an additional binding offset of 10mm.

```
\documentclass[
     12pt,                     % font size
     a4paper,                  % paper format
     BCOR=10mm,                % binding correction
     DIV=12,                   % stripe size for margin calculation
     listof=totoc,             % table listing in toc
     bibliography=totoc,       % bibliography in toc
     index=totoc,              % index in toc
     twoside=semi,
     headsepline
     ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I do not recommended this, because if you open a normal book, you will usually see that each outer margin has nearly the same size as the two inner margins together. It could look like this:

[image]

But there is also space at the inner margin needed for binding. Note that this binding offset (red in the following picture) is not visible in the open book. For the following picture `BCOR=10mm` is used.

[image]

If `twoside=semi` is used, the inner and outer margins have the same width

[image]

But the open book will then look similar to the following picture - the inner margins seem to wide when they are next to each other.

[image]

---

Code for the colored pictures:

```
\documentclass[
     12pt,                     % font size
     a4paper,                  % paper format
     BCOR=10mm,                % binding correction
     DIV=12,                   % stripe size for margin calculation
     listof=totoc,             % table listing in toc
     bibliography=totoc,       % bibliography in toc
     index=totoc,              % index in toc
     twoside=true,% or 
     %twoside = semi,
     headsepline
     ]{scrreprt}

\newlength\bcor
\setlength\bcor{0mm}% or 
%\setlength\bcor{1cm}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=\bcor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand\marginrule[1][yellow!50]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\layerwidth}{\layerheight}}}
\newcommand\showlayerwidth[1]{%
  \centering\vfill
  \rotatebox{90}{\ifdim\layerwidth>20pt\LARGE #1\,=\,\the\layerwidth\fi}%
  \vfill
}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  innermargin,
  width=\bcor,
  contents={\marginrule[red!20]}
]{bindingoffset.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  evenpage,
  innermargin,
  align=r,
  hoffset=\paperwidth,
  width=\bcor,
  contents={\marginrule[red!20]}
]{bindingoffset.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=bindingoffset.odd,
  foreground,
  contents=\showlayerwidth{binding offset}
]{bindingtext.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=bindingoffset.even,
  foreground,
  contents=\showlayerwidth{binding offset}
]{bindingtext.even}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  oddpage,
  innermargin,
  addhoffset=\bcor,
  addwidth=-\bcor,
  contents=\marginrule
]{innermargin.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  evenpage,
  innermargin,
  addwidth=-\bcor,
  contents=\marginrule
]{innermargin.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=innermargin.odd,
  foreground,
  contents=\showlayerwidth{inner margin (odd page)}
]{innertext.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=innermargin.even,
  foreground,
  contents=\showlayerwidth{inner margin (even page)}
]{innertext.even}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  outermargin,
  contents=\marginrule
]{outermargin}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  outermargin,
  contents=\showlayerwidth{outer width}
]{outertext}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  oddpage,
  head,
  contents=\LARGE\hfill\textcolor{red}{odd page}
]{oddpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  evenpage,
  head,
  contents=\LARGE\textcolor{red}{even page}
]{evenpage}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  twoside,
  foot,
  contents=\parbox{\layerwidth}{\ifodd\value{page}\hfill\fi\pagemark}
]{pagenumber}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  topmargin,
  contents=\layercontentsmeasure
]{ruler}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{showmargins}{% or not needed layers commented
  bindingoffset.odd,bindingoffset.even,%
  bindingtext.odd,bindingtext.even,%
  innermargin.odd,innermargin.even,%
  innertext.odd,innertext.even,%
  outermargin,outertext,%
  pagenumber,%
  oddpage,evenpage,%
  ruler%
}

\pagestyle{showmargins}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```