# Verso Pages Lack Binding Correction

Tags: margins, binding

While the recto pages of the attached book project display the proper binding correction, the verso pages do not. How can I fix this, since binding will cut off the text? Here is a MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[11pt,headsepline]{bookest}
\pdfpagewidth=4.25in 
\pdfpageheight=7.0in
\geometry{paperwidth=108mm,paperheight=178mm,bottom=.75in,bindingoffset=8mm} 
\addtolength{\textwidth}{.4in} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The lengths `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` may be of use here.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319108/document-left-space-is-on-wrong-side

Comment: Taking the lead from my answer at the above cited question, you could add `\addtolength\evensidemargin{6pt}` just before `\begin{document}` to adjust just the verso page shift.

Comment: If I use a large value for bindingoffset (bindingoffset=3cm) it is used on both sides. So this is not the problem. The problem is your `\addtolength\textwidth`. Use `\geometry{textwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth +0.4in}` instead.

Comment: @Ulrike  Could you explain what \dimexpr means?

Comment: "dimension expression", you can use it to calculate dimensions.

Comment: @Ulrike--this worked well. Could you write this as an answer? Secondly, shouldn't \typearea or a Koma package do these calculations automatically?